# Json array move to top

Tags: php, json

I'm showing the JSON with this code:

```
<?php
$result = array();
array_push($result,
    array("id" => 1, "title" => "text 1"),
    array("id" => 2, "title" => "text 2"),
    array("id" => 3, "title" => "text 3"),
    array("id" => 4, "title" => "text 4")
);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

I want to move the id 3 to the top. Is this possible? How can I do it?

The result should be like this:

```
[
    {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "text 3"
    },
    {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "text 1"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "text 2"
    },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "text 4"
    }
]
```

Comment: What text editor do you use?

Comment: notepad++ @steffen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array before JSON encoding it.

```
$move_to_top = 3;

usort($result, function($a, $b) use ($move_to_top) {
    if ($a['id'] == $move_to_top) return -1;
    if ($b['id'] == $move_to_top) return 1;
    return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
});
```

This does sort the array. If you want to leave the current order alone other than moving the one item, you can iterate it, and when you find the id you want, unset the current key and then append the item to the beginning of the array.

```
$move_to_top = 3;

foreach($result as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['id'] == $move_to_top) {
        unset($result[$key]);
        array_unshift($result, $item);
        break;
    }
}
```

`json_encode` after you've moved the item to the top.

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: This sorts the array as a side-effect.

Comment: @steffen That's true. I added a different method if that's unwanted.

Comment: Hi again @Don'tPanic Which method should I use?

Comment: Hi, @EagleH. Both will move the item with id=3 to the top. The only difference in effect is that first one will sort the remaining items as well, and the second one will leave them in the original order (which may be the same if they were already sorted), so whichever one of those sounds better to you :)

Answer (score 2):

[`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) can help:

```
$out = array_splice($result, 2, 1);
array_splice($result, 0, 0, $out);
```

Result:

```
[{"id":3,"title":"text 3"},{"id":1,"title":"text 1"},{"id":2,"title":"text 2"},{"id":4,"title":"text 4"}]
```

Comment: Ah, good point. I was assuming you wouldn't necessarily know where the item with the id you wanted was in the array as we do in this example, but maybe I'm overcomplicating the issue.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I thought about this as well when I read your answer :)